# Show the pdf blob string in the frontend as preview

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have three different document types. In the Schemas of Mongodb, one is BescheidG to store all the document fields. The work flow is like upload documents and display them as list and when you select one,you can see the details on the right side. They have differnt document fields. I can display three document according to their document type. Now i just want to show the pdf preview so i created Another schema which is pdf.

```
var bescheidG = new Schema({
  document_id:  { type: String, required: true },
  pdf_id: String,
  ...(other properties)...
  document_type: { type: String },
 });

var pdf = new Schema({
  pdf_id: String,
  pdf_stream: String
})
```

I want store the pdf as one big stream and store in the mongodb

```
router.put("/documents/:id", async (ctx, next) => {
    let data = await ModelDb.update(ctx.params.id, ctx.request.body);
    ctx.body = data;
})

update(id, obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const pdf_id = generate_id()
      schemas.pdf.create({pdf_id: pdf_id, pdf_stream: obj.pdf})
      obj.pdf_id = id
      obj.pdf = undefined
      schemas.bescheidG.findOneAndUpdate(
        { document_id: id },
        obj,
        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log("Update successgully")
          resolve(res);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

i used postmann to test,it updated the bescheidG and added pdf_id in the schema.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jSrv.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxjGS.png)

when i want to display pdf in the frontend,it is null. Error is that pdf_id and pdf_stream are null from the chrome console.

comparison.component.ts

```
getPDF() {
    console.log("getting PDF");
    this.pdf.pdf_id = this.currdoc.document_id;
    console.log("getting id " + this.currdoc.document_id);
    return timer(0, 5000)
      .pipe(
        flatMap(() =>
          this.http.get<pdf[]>(environment.host + "documents/pdf" + this.pdf.pdf_id).pipe(
            map(data => {
              this.pdfs = data;
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("PDF Data fetched.")
        console.log(this.pdfs);
      });
  }
```

comparison.component.html

```
<object *ngIf="pdfs" [data]="pdfs"  [class.compare-pdf-wide]="pdfs.opened" [class.compare-pdf-slim]="!pdfs.opened" ></object>
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        [class.active]="pdfs.opened"
        matTooltip="Show the uploaded PDF file."
      >
        <mat-icon>filter_1</mat-icon>
      </button>
```

If anyone could give me advice or suggestion, i would be so appreciate. I m new to angular and mongodb and i would like to learn more from anyone. Thank you.